# jquery get end number in option

Tags: jquery

i have this html code into my page, i can get first 3 number and between of `()`

**HTML:**

```
<option value="702(3)00">
```

**jQuery:**

```
max_exam=$('#at_exam_'+val+' option').filter(":selected").val().match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1];
exam_code=$('#at_exam_'+val+' option').filter(":selected").val().match(/^\d+/);
```

how to get `00` end of option value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use split method:

```
var value = $('#at_exam_'+val+' option').filter(":selected").val(),
    parts = value.split(/\(|\)/);
```

will give you `parts` as an array:

```
["702", "3", "00"]
```

Comment: also of note: doing this will enable OP to do the expensive jQuery selection and filtering once instead of three times.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of ways to do it. I like dfsq's answer, but you can also do the same idea as your `exam_code` assignment above, just using the end of line instead of the beginning of line match:

```
last_group=$('#at_exam_'+val+' option').filter(":selected").val().match(/\d+$/);
```